# Graphics Driver in Intel Desktop Board DQ77MK

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, motherboard, intel-graphics, intel-core-i5

I just baught a used Intel Desktop Board DQ77MK which works almost as expected. Everything is up and running with the following exception:

If i use the Windows 7 Standard VGA graphics drivers they do work fine (slow but fine) even in full HD.

If i install the Intel HD Graphics drivers from the intel homepage the PC boots and after the Windows Logo there will be a greenish flickering soup of pixels on the screen. (See attached image).

As soon as i boot to the (secure mode? i don't know the english word) and i remove the intel drivers everything is back to normal. I already flashed the latest bios update.

I'm not sure about what is wrong here because the graphics chip basically seems to work well.[image]

Comment: Have you used the automatic detection tool, the one that opens in a web page? Or something that you downloaded yourself?

Comment: For choosing the driver i just used the intel website. I identified the Mainboard with a look into the bios. And then i searched for "DQ77MK" on the website, and chose the Intel HD Graphics Driver for Windows 7 64-bit matching my OS.

I installed the drivers in two different ways. 1: using the downloaded installer, 2. using the "manual" method described in the readme (basically just using the windows dialogs to choose and "update" the downloaded driver). Both with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the driver you're installing is:

a) Newer than Microsoft's, and official
b) Specifically for your card
c) Properly signed fulfilling conditions above

That last point I'm referring to it's because it's a common practice to disable Windows's driver signature check in order to be able to install some drivers, so basically anything can pass through. If it's not the case, be sure your driver fulfills points a and b. If it doesn't, don't worry, lately a lot of companies have been including ther old/generic drivers in Windows Update so you don't have to install them manually, like intel hd graphics driver.

However, if the driver is up to date, newer than microsoft's, specific for your card and properly signed, there's always the chance that the chip is damaged and when it trying to function at 100% capacity (like when it has a proper driver managing it), it just fails to. But in my experience, it's highly unlikeable. I'll focus on the driver.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it newer ? I can't say i couldn't find the date of the Standard VGA Driver from mircrosoft. Yes i'ts the official driver from the Intel website. Yes it's specifially for my mainboard (and so for my graphics chip). I don't know why but the microsoft driver seems to be remarkably slower the higher resolution i choose. So in full hd scrolling stuff is a bit "unsmooth".

Comment: Well, on one hand, those integrated graphic cards aren't very powerful. On the other, they usually give a good performace when using it for non-specific graphic tasks (like games or video rendering). Try to boot from a usb with your favorite linux flavor (ask if you don't know how) and do some checks like opening hd video or whatever you need to do. If you can't feel remarkable performance differences between SOs, you have to consider the damage option seriously. But if you do, there's still more things we can check (like aero settings, directX, memory mapping, etc.).

Comment: Actually on my other home PC the Intel HD Graphics Chip has a awesome performance (taking into account that it's not a full blown graphics card). So the damaged option gets more and more realistic.

Comment: Sorry to read that. Try the linux usb if you can to be sure. Have you checked if you can configure the amount of memory shared with the graphic card? I forgot to ask, is this a sudden problem or has it been progressive?